# Variable price doesn't change to reflect buyer's choice due to Autoship for WooCommerce

Tags: variables, woocommerce, price

A previous developer reconfigured how the price shows on variable products that also use the [Autoship for WooCommerce](https://wooautoship.com/) plugin options. However the price is not changing as per the variations chosen on the variable product drop down.

I've located the code that displays that price but don't know what I need to change it to to make it actually reflect the variation price - not the previously chosen price.

```
$price = $product->get_price();

$autoship_min_frequency = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_wc_autoship_min_frequency', true );

$autoship_max_frequency = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_wc_autoship_max_frequency', true );

$autoship_default_frequency = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_wc_autoship_default_frequency', true );

$autoship_price = '';
```

https://dev.espressovivace.com/product/vita-blend/

The "One-time price:" should change depending on what bean/blend is chosen, as well as the "Auto-ship price:"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Zoey. Please note that your link is access controlled and is probably only available within your organization. Please consider other ways to show the outcome and expected results. It would probably also help with more context than your code (unless this is obvious to other WooCommerce users, that is).